# Why is DotNetNuke text editor control always showing HTML Code with iPad?

Tags: ipad, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I have a DotNetNuke custom module where I am using an HTML editor to allow uses to enter some text to be saved to a database.
It is working fine for all browsers except IPad's safari where I get the HTML tags showing in the editor.

What can I do to make Ipad show text formatted (or even as plain text) rather than having these tags appear as they are very confusing to users.

The control is using:

```
   <%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="TextEditor"  Src="~/controls/TextEditor.ascx" %>

      <div id="divTab2">
             <dnn:TextEditor ID="txtNotes" runat="server" Width="900px" />
         </div>
```

The web.config has this:

```
 <htmlEditor defaultProvider="DotNetNuke.RadEditorProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <!--Upgraded by DotNetNuke.TelerikEditorProvider version 5.6.3 - Date: 8/3/2011 1:00:02 AM-->
        <!--<add name="TelerikEditorProvider" type="DotNetNuke.HtmlEditor.TelerikEditorProvider.EditorProvider, DotNetNuke.HtmlEditor.TelerikEditorProvider" providerPath="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/" toolsFile="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/Config/ToolsDefault.xml" configFile="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/Config/ConfigDefault.xml" FilterHostExtensions="True" />-->
        <!--Upgraded by DotNetNuke.TelerikEditorProvider version 5.6.3 - Date: 8/3/2011 7:33:08 PM-->
        <!--<add name="TelerikEditorProvider" type="DotNetNuke.HtmlEditor.TelerikEditorProvider.EditorProvider, DotNetNuke.HtmlEditor.TelerikEditorProvider" providerPath="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/" toolsFile="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/Config/ToolsDefault.xml" configFile="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/Config/ConfigDefault.xml" FilterHostExtensions="True" />-->
        <add name="TelerikEditorProvider" type="DotNetNuke.HtmlEditor.TelerikEditorProvider.EditorProvider, DotNetNuke.HtmlEditor.TelerikEditorProvider" providerPath="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/" toolsFile="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/Config/ToolsDefault.xml" configFile="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/Config/ConfigDefault.xml" FilterHostExtensions="True" />
        <add name="DotNetNuke.RadEditorProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Providers.RadEditorProvider.EditorProvider, DotNetNuke.RadEditorProvider" providerPath="~/DesktopModules/Admin/RadEditorProvider" />
      </providers>
    </htmlEditor>
```

example:
In iPad, I get

```
 <div style="text-align: center;"><strong>Case History Notes - Martha </strong><br /></div><br /><strong>6/24/11</strong>: Referred by Jackie <br /><strong>6/26/11:</strong>&nbsp; Sch. Initial Interview for 6/30; 7:00AM Breakfast at Cafe.<br />
```

rather than the expected

**Case History Notes - Martha** 
**6/24/11**: Referred by Jackie 
**6/26/11:**  Sch. Initial Interview for 6/30; 7:00AM Breakfast at Cafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari on the iThings doesn't support `contentEditable`, which is the feature used for most rech edit panels on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have an iPad, I am unable to troubleshoot this.  I can confirm that the desktop version of Safari works fine though.  Have you tried this on newer versions of DotNetNuke?  The browser and telerik definitions are updated with every release.  If you cannot upgrade for some reason, I would try upgrading just your telerik controls.  For example, you can try the latest release of the [DNN 5 RadEditor Provider by dnnWerk](http://radeditor.codeplex.com/).